# How to Eliminate Duplicate Permutations of Weights?

Tags: ranking, permutation

I am creating a computer simulation to reverse-engineer a ranking vector. For example, assume I had 3 variables I was measuring, and wanted to apply a weighting vector to them with values from 1-5. I would then apply the weights to the variable vector, creating a rating vector. Then convert that to a ranking vector, and see which permutation was the closest to the standard. How could I eliminate the duplicates like the weighting vectors:

(1,1,1) produces the same ranking vector as (5,5,5)

(2,1,1) produces the same ranking vector as (4,2,2)

etc.

My actual simulation has many more variables/weights and eliminating duplicates would really help save processing power.

Comment: Is this a fair understanding: you wish to generate a complete set of n-tuples (x1,x2,...,xn) with the xi *integral* in 1..5, but you will consider any such tuple of the form (a*x1,a*x2,...,a*xn) to be equivalent to (x1,x2,...,xn)? E.g., (5,5,5) = 5*(1,1,1) and (4,2,2) = 2*(2,1,1). If so, I wouldn't bother weeding them out: you would be eliminating only 2^n+3 out of the 5^n possible n-tuples, which even for small n is an inconsequential fraction of the total.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll just have to keep the number of parameters low to bring the permutations down.